# my mqtt client is not able to connect with mqtt broker

Tags: python, sockets, mqtt, python-sockets

I have done socket programming in python for my TCP based device now I want to send data to mqtt broker from this socket program so I tried to do my program like this but I am not able to connect to the broker can anyone help me to find out what mistake I am making.

```
import socket
from obd_data import packet_splitter
HOST = '127.0.0.2'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import random
import json
broker_ip="127.0.0.1"
broker_port="1883"
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
   s.bind((HOST, PORT))
   s.listen()
   conn, addr = s.accept()
   try:
       client = mqtt.Client(str(addr))  # create new instance
       client.connect(broker_ip, broker_port, 60)  # connect to broker
  except:
       print("not connected to mqtt")
 with conn:
    print('Connected by', addr)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        a= data.hex().upper()
        topic = "device/{}/message".format(client)
        payload = {
            "param1": a,
        }
        if client.is_connected():
            client.publish(topic, json.dumps(payload))
            print("{} - message sent: {} - {}".format(client, topic, json.dumps(payload)))
        else:
            print("{} is not connected to the broker!".format(client))

        print("=============================")
        if not data:
            break

        conn.sendall((bytes.fromhex('AA00')))
```

Comment: Where are you running the MQTT client network loop?

Comment: i am using on my local pc

Comment: That wasn't the question. Read the Paho Python [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#network-loop) about the network loop